# When VPN is connected it disconnects other clients connections to the server

Tags: server, 20.04, internet, vpn, connection

[Connecting to EnterpriseVPN Gateway from Ubuntu 20.04](https://medium.com/@levsoroka/connecting-to-enterprisevpn-gateway-from-ubuntu-20-04-d386c20bce87)

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed the tutorial here to install and connect to a VPN, which worked brilliantly. I'm using PuTTy and WinScp to connect. After connecting using PuTTy, I noticed that all other clients connected to the server get disconnected, and I can't connect again until I disconnect the VPN.

Please, what do I do as I need to execute some command while connected to the VPN. I'm running a load test on the website behind VPN.